# How do I build a regular expression to replace only the first "$" after a "//" with "\$"?

Tags: python, regex

**Input:**

//bla bla $Log$

**Output:**

//bla bla \$Log$

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.sub("(?<=\/\/)([^\$]+)\$",r"\1\\$", "abc$ $ //bla bla $Log$ //bla bla $Log$ //bla bla bla bla bla $Log$ $ $")
abc$ $ //bla bla \$Log$ //bla bla \$Log$ //bla bla bla bla bla \$Log$ $ $
```

Comment: Input: 
abc$
$
//bla bla $Log$ 
//bla bla $Log$ 
//bla bla bla bla bla $Log$ $ $

Output 
abc$
$
//bla bla \$Log\$ 
//bla bla \$Log\$ 
//bla bla bla bla bla \$Log\$ \$ \$

What if only the $ after // should be replace with \$?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I adapted my answer and also the question itself according to this comment. If my answer helped you please mark it as useful. Thanks!